# xmppsream connection issue in iOS - Unable to authenticate with password

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am developing a chat system in both iOS. The chat server which I am using is ejabbered server. I am using Robbiehanson `xmppframework` for iOS chat client.

The issue which I am facing is that I am not able to establish a proper  xmppstream between the chat client and the server. The xmppstream state is in `STATE_XMPP_REGISTERING`. This holds a value of 8. Due to this,when I try to authenticate the just created registered  user, I am encountering an exception

```
"Error authenticating: Error Domain=XMPPStreamErrorDomain Code=1 "Please wait until the stream is connected." UserInfo=0x166c1e30 {NSLocalizedDescription=Please wait until the stream is connected.}
```

But surprisingly, I am able to register a user using a password. When I try to authenticate the user, I am encountering this exception due to which the registered user is not able to appear ONLINE.

I am using `ConnectWithTimeOut` to connect the xmppstream to the server

```
NSString *myPassword = @"password";

if (myJID == nil || myPassword == nil) {
    return NO;
}

[xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];
password = myPassword;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error connecting"
                                                        message:@"See console for error details."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];        
    DDLogError(@"Error connecting: %@", error);        
    return NO;
}
```

Using this above code, I am able to establish a connection to the server.

Once the connectton is established, xmppStreamDidConnect is invoked.

when I checked the status of the XMPPStream, I am seeing the stream is connected.
Below is the code.

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
```

{

```
if ([xmppStream isDisconnected]){
    NSLog(@"Is DisConnected");
    [self connect];
}

if ([xmppStream isConnecting]){
    NSLog(@"Is Connecting");
}

if ([xmppStream isConnecting]){
    NSLog(@"Is Connecting");
}

if ([xmppStream isConnected]){
    NSLog(@"Is Connected");
}


NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self xmppStream]  registerWithPassword:@"password" error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Registration error: %@", error);
}

    if (![[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:password error:&error])
    {
        DDLogError(@"Error authenticating: %@", error);
    }else{
        [self goOnline];
        XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"available"];
        [sender sendElement:presence];

    }
```

As per the above code, a user is registered and here comes the issue. When I try to authenticate the user, using `authenticateWithPassword:password`

```
XMPPLogTrace();

// The given password parameter could be mutable
NSString *password = [inPassword copy];


__block BOOL result = YES;
__block NSError *err = nil;

dispatch_block_t block = ^{ @autoreleasepool {

    if (state != STATE_XMPP_CONNECTED)
    {
        NSString *errMsg = @"Please wait until the stream is connected.";
        NSDictionary *info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:errMsg forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];

        err = [NSError errorWithDomain:XMPPStreamErrorDomain code:XMPPStreamInvalidState userInfo:info];

        result = NO;
        return_from_block;
    }

    if (myJID_setByClient == nil)
    {
        NSString *errMsg = @"You must set myJID before calling authenticate:error:.";
        NSDictionary *info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:errMsg forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];

        err = [NSError errorWithDomain:XMPPStreamErrorDomain code:XMPPStreamInvalidProperty userInfo:info];

        result = NO;
        return_from_block;
    }
```

the code below gets executed. But when I check the status of the xmppstream when I enter this delegate, I am seeing it in status 8 (which is STATE_XMPP_REGISTERING) though the user is successfully registered. This status makes to return a NO and hence the registered user is not appearing online.

Could anyone please help me in resolving this issue. I tried a lot of ways. But not able to progress.

Why I am not able to move to the next status and ultimately to status 12 before the `authenticatewithpassword` is invoked. Am I missing any intermediate steps after establishing a connection and successful registration. In nutshell, why the stream state stops at 8. and not going forward to 
`STATE_XMPP_AUTH,STATE_XMPP_BINDING`,`STATE_XMPP_START_SESSION`, `STATE_XMPP_CONNECTED`, before getting into `authenticatewithpassword`

Logs for more info.

```
2014-05-30 07:40:20:995 konnectlinks[3249:8403] SEND: <?xml version='1.0'?>
2014-05-30 07:40:20:996 konnectlinks[3249:8403] SEND: <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='localhost'>
2014-05-30 07:40:21.246 konnectlinks[3249:60b] dhaval is here 
2014-05-30 07:40:21:608 konnectlinks[3249:4717] RECV: <stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" id="114321716" from="localhost" version="1.0" stream1:lang="en"/>
2014-05-30 07:40:21:609 konnectlinks[3249:8403] RECV: <stream:features xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/" ver="9DVbXp9C/vTyB5mLfy7wktk5Pfs="/><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features>
2014-05-30 07:40:21.610 konnectlinks[3249:8403] -[XMPPReconnect xmppStreamDidConnect:]
2014-05-30 07:41:01.558 konnectlinks[3249:60b] Is Connected
2014-05-30 07:41:01.561 konnectlinks[3249:8403] -[XMPPReconnect setMultipleReachabilityChanges:]
2014-05-30 07:41:14.073 konnectlinks[3249:8403] -[XMPPReconnect setManuallyStarted:]
2014-05-30 07:41:14.076 konnectlinks[3249:8403] -[XMPPReconnect teardownReconnectTimer]
2014-05-30 07:41:14:076 konnectlinks[3249:60b] SEND: <iq type="set"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:register"><username>timop</username><password>password</password></query></iq>
2014-05-30 07:41:14.077 konnectlinks[3249:8403] -[XMPPReconnect teardownNetworkMonitoring]
2014-05-30 07:42:07:428 konnectlinks[3249:860b] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="localhost" type="result"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:register"><username>timop</username><password>password</password></query></iq>
2014-05-30 07:42:10:312 konnectlinks[3249:60b] Error authenticating: Error Domain=XMPPStreamErrorDomain Code=1 "Please wait until the stream is connected." UserInfo=0x166c1e30 {NSLocalizedDescription=Please wait until the stream is connected.}
```

I am sure someone would have encountered the issue.

Please help me in resolving this issue. Advance thanks for your time and help

Comment: Did you solved the issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the code seems its right , Make sure the username and password you send it must be correct.
If nothing goes right then contact with your server/web team regarding this or try to connect with creating new user